# S3 v3 authentication Go SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I want to access S3 using v2 authentication compliant Go SDK(authentication version used prior to v4). While going through the S3 releases, I didn't get any particular release with v3/v2 authentication mentioned in the release documents. 
Can somebody point towards the required Go SDK from amazon or other provider. Also need the relevant client for the same.

Comment: Why V3? Please provide a citation from the S3 documentation  indicating that "V3" is supported by S3 itself.  To my knowledge, only V2 and V4 are supported by S3.

Comment: Thanks Michael. In my use case, I was using v4 and got an error but needed authentication version used prior to that. I thought v3 would be the natural choice for that, didn't knew that v3 doesn't exist. Can you help me with the v2 version of Go SDK now? Also let me know where this authentication info has been described.

Comment: *In my use case, I was using v4 and got an error but needed authentication version used prior to that.* ...I'm not sure the best solution is going to be to use the older version -- S3 regions deployed in 2014 or later only support V4.  Please consider expanding the question to describe the underlying problem rather than how you are trying to solve it.  See http://xyproblem.info.